# Switching quickly between versions

Tags: git, vim

Let's say I have a file `f.txt` under the `git` repository. The initial version of this file contains one line, version 2 contains 2 lines and every new version adds one line to the previous version, so the version 10 contains 10 lines.

Now, I open the file `f.txt` (in 5th version) in the vim editor. I'd like to stay in the vim editor and have the possibility of commands like `git_next` and `git_previous` and quickly switch between versions, without having to know commit numbers and without leaving `vim`.

Is there such a possibility of using `git` and `vim`? It would be also useful if I could type command like `git_versions` and I could choose from the list of versions of this file and switch to the desired version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for [Fugitive.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) plugin by Tim Pope. It can aid you with many `git` commands.

With fugitive.vim you can execute `:Glog` and the revisions will be put into the `quickfix` list. Just use `:cnext`, `:cprev`, and friends to move between the revisions. There is an excellent screencast, [Fugitive.vim - exploring the history of a git repository](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/fugitive-vim-exploring-the-history-of-a-git-repository/), on this by Drew Neil. I would highly recommend watching all the [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) on the subject.

Drew in the screencast also shows off another Tim Pope plugin called [Unimpaired.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired). I highly recommend it. It will provide some nice mappings (`[q`, `]q`, etc.) to move through the `quickfix` list.

For more help see:

```
:h quickfix
:h :cnext
```

If you have Fugitive.vim installed see:

```
:h fugitive
:h fugitive-:Glog
```